# how can i use loop to lock the cell range through all the existing worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a exist workbook which has more than 50 worksheet. i need to lock the cell range (b7:b51) for each of the exist worksheet. i try to use loop to do it and i have a code for loop which does go through all the worksheet, i need put the correct code to lock the cell.

```
   Sub WorksheetLoop()

     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 2 To WS_Count

   ActiveSheet.range("B1:B51").locked=true. --this is not correct.


    MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name


     Next I

  End Sub
```

thank

Comment: Do you only want `B7:B51` locked and all other cells unlocked?  By default, cells are `Locked` for when you protect the sheet.  You actually have to `unlock` the cells you want to use and leave the others as they are `locked`.

Comment: yes i only need B7:B51 locked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

 Dim WS_Count As Integer
 Dim I As Integer

 ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
 ' workbook.
 WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

 ' Begin the loop.
 For I = 1 To WS_Count

If Worksheets(I).Range("C1:C51").Locked <> True Then
  Worksheets(I).Range("C1:C51").Locked = True
  Worksheets(I).Protect Contents:=True
Else
End If

MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name


 Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: I try the code and it shows something wrong with this line
Worksheets(I).Range("B1:B281").Locked = True

Comment: Alright. it seems these cells are already locked.

Try this

If Worksheets(I).Range("B1:B51").Locked <> True Then

    Worksheets(I).Range("B1:B51").Locked = True

    Worksheets(I).Protect Contents:=True

Else

End If

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Sub ProtectRange()
Dim i As Integer, wsCount As Integer

wsCount = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For i = 1 To wsCount
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("B1:B51").Locked = True
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Protect Contents:=True
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. but i get error in this line:   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("B1:B281").Locked = True

Comment: @user1723572 What is the error message? I ran it in a test workbook and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 2 To WS_Count

        Dim sheet As Worksheet
        Set sheet = Sheets(I)

        sheet.Unprotect

        sheet.UsedRange.Locked = False
        sheet.Range("B7:B51").Locked = True
        sheet.Protect Contents:=True

        MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I).Name

     Next I

End Sub
```